# Who said "Anything a machine can do, a machine should do"?

Tags: quotes

Alternately, "anything that can be done by a machine, should be done by a machine".

I have heard variants of these quotes attributed to Brigham Young, but I have not been able to find any reliable sources to confirm that. If he did say something like this, I would like to know where it is documented; and if not, I'd like to know who the quote can be properly attributed to, and what its proper context is.

Comment: Can you tell us where you have heard or seen this? Any links to sources (reliable or otherwise) might help people trying to answer your question.